# How To Use An Array (Associative) As Header?

Tags: php, arrays, url, redirect, header

```
if ($source=="test") {
header("Location: $testurl['google']"); 
}
```

This is supposed to redirect to google.com if the url is example.com/redirect.php?source=test but it doesn't work. If I change the array key to 1 and change the location to $testurl[1] it does works. Why does it work with indexed but not associative arrays?

Comment: its typo, use as `if ($source=="test") {
    $url = $testurl['google'];
header("Location:$url"); 
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have somewhere an array `$testurl` which has an element `google`:

```php
$testurl = [
  'google' => 'https://google.pl'
];
```

Then you can use it like this:

```php
if ($source=="test") {
    header("Location: $testurl[google]"); 
}
```

or

```php
if ($source=="test") {
    header("Location: {$testurl['google']}"); 
}
```

or in my opinion the best option, like this:

```php
if ($source=="test") {
    header('Location: ' . $testurl['google']); 
}
```

It is simply how it is defined:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

There is a sentence:

```
// Works, quoted keys only work using the curly brace syntax
echo "This works: {$arr['key']}";
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I used the best option.